# Changing title with javascript and related issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So changing title of website with javascript is not so difficult:

```
document.title = 'title';
```

However I set the title from a user set variable:

```
document.title = userVar; // where userVar is a variable set by a user
```

And this is where it gets annoying. Since the variable is set by a user, it could contain just about anything. Characters like `!@#$%^&*()_+=-` or even `'"` or `unicode characters` or even scripts `<script>alert('');</script>`. Basically, there are many combinations user can input as a variable to break our page. How can we implement something like:

```
document.title = clean(userVar);
```

***Bonus PHP question:**
We could also encounter similar problems when setting title of a page from php variables. How do we clean variables so that they can be used as website titles?*

Comment: filter it to only allow characters. something like [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: @Dexa yes but this will also block unicode characters, which aren't necessarily harmful

Comment: In what sense do those characters or quotation marks "break" the page when applied as the `document.title`?

Comment: @Dexa: what about other languages?  Plus, I think that they are escaped by default - no need to do so.

Comment: Just curious... why are you letting your users set the title? It seems odd that you'd let them control this aspect of your site/app.

Comment: @scunliffe imagine a dynamic page, let's say with chats. And you try to change the title of the page to something like "username messaged you: blah blah" when someone messages

Comment: Other languages characters probably aren't harmful, so include them if you like, but I prefer white listing where you allow what can be added, instead of removing whats bad. I don't see need for title to have more then regular characters and maybe some dash in it. I didn't provide full regular expression, just an idea what OP should look at.

Comment: So if you want to display what a user types in the title and the user happens to type something like your example `<script>alert('');</script>` why would you _not_ want that reflected faithfully in the title? (Notice I managed to type it in my comment and it displayed fine without breaking Stack Overflow...)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be safe. Any tags or code adding in the title tag are not executed by default.

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including comments).

Source: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2)

From what I can see/test in various browsers, all characters in the title tag are considered as plain text.

Comment: Yup this seems to be the case for php. Anything you put into the title tags, it is taken as text.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP you can simple use strip_tags which will at least remove the script tags:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegExp to sanitize `userVar`

**Javascript**

[MDN String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
function clean(userVar){
   return userVar.replace(/\W+/ig, "");
}
```

**PHP**

[PHP preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
function clean($userVar){
   return preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $userVar)
}
```